# Multiple password prompts on resume from sleep: "Authentication is required to refresh system sources"

Tags: security, suspend

I've recently installed 0.4 Kodi Beta 2 on my XPS 13 as the broadcom WiFi chip installed on it only started receiving support on Ubuntu starting 16.04 on which 0.4 Kodi is based.
So far everything has been working wonderfully (except for a few minor bugs in the software centre), but there's one thing that boggles me and I'd love to hear your input on it.
Every time I resume the laptop from sleep, I get this popup asking for my password:
[image]
Sometimes I even have to input my password in several times because after clicking "Authenticate" the window shows up again.
Is this a known bug? Does anyone know how to resolve it?

Comment: This is still occurring even after a fresh install of Elementary OS Loki post official release. Does anyone know how to deal with it?

Comment: I've been getting this too, for the last 3 or 4 days. The only way I've been dealing with it so far has been to open a terminal and use xkill to kill the popup... a proper fix would be nice!

Comment: What other applications do you have open when you get this pop-up? Mail, perhaps?

Comment: I have Chrome running in the background, dropbox, and that's it...

Comment: This is happening to me too as of March 20, 2018 and a fresh Elementary OS install.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**: Should be [fixed in the AppCenter 1.2 update](https://bugs.launchpad.net/appcenter/+bug/1617687), but try the following if it persists:

---

I haven't had this issue since I disabled the AppCenter from running in the background.

- To kill AppCenter in your current session, run `killall appcenter`.
- To disable AppCenter at startup, see [Disable AppCenter dock reminder](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/8629/5565)—there is a `terminal` way and a `gnome-session-properties` way.

Comment: In my case there is no process "appcenter" running. Still getting the prompt...

Answer (score 8):

Its a bug, already reported:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/appcenter/+bug/1617687

Im also affected, hope it will get fixed soon.

Comment: Good to know it's not just me. I hope a fix will be released sometime soon.

Comment: I still have this issue and I want to keep AppCenter running so I know when to grab OS updates. Was a new bug report opened since?

Comment: That launchpad bug is closed. There's one on appcenter (https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/499) that's still open though.

Answer (score 4):

Removing the App Center works for me.

`sudo apt purge appcenter`

You can always reinstall it later; after the problems are addressed maybe :).

Comment: a workaround I guess for now ... but certainly not a cure.