# On resume from suspend: Authentication required doesn't accept system password

Tags: suspend

On resume from suspend, elementary OS prompts: "Authentication is required to refresh system resources" - but my password doesn't get accepted by this dialog, just had to press cancel. Anyone having experience with this? Password works fine in terminal, though.

Comment: Searching on "Authentication is required" gave: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7447/multiple-password-prompts-on-resume-from-sleep-authentication-is-required-to-r  
Seems like a duplicate question?

Comment: No, it is not actually, for in this case the password doesn't work and it's the system password of course.. The only workaround is to cancel the dialog.

Comment: Same here, for all users on a desktop. Only workaround is to cancel the dialog.